# What kind of object I should pass from DAL to BLL if I need to create custom type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I don't know what kind of object I should pass from DAL to BLL if I need to create custom type.
In DAL I have an entity:

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

But I need to return to BLL only: **NoteId, Content and number of comments** which aren't spam so in DAL I have a query:

```
public IEnumerable<WhatIsIt> GetNotesWithNoSpamCommentsCount()
{
    var whatIsIt = context.Notes.Select(x =>
        new WhatIsIt
        {
            NoteId = x.NoteId,
            NoteSummary = x.Content,
            NoteCommentsCount = x.Comments.Where(y => y.IsSpam == false).Count() 
        }).ToList();

    return whatIsIt;
}
```

What kind of object is it which I return - is it Data Access Object or Model or Data Transfer Object or Business Object or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As per the code you've written, it could be your DTO(Date transfer object).
I assume here that `Note` is your entity class. So, it wouldn't best practices to use entity class to transfer the data between layers.

You can use DTO object to transfer data with required properties only. But again keep in mind, your viewpage need a model class to bind the data. So you've to map your DTO to your entity class with using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or other library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Note` is his DTO is it not? Not his VM? His VM should be a new class with just Id, Content and Comments properties? Or am I wrong?

Comment: What is DTO in the context of entity framework then?

Comment: @Mardoxx: There are three different things, Entity classes, ViewModeles and DTO. Basically, Entity classes contains definition of tables and use to perform DB related things. Viewmodel is use to bind your data to the view. and DTO is use to transfer data.

Comment: @Mardoxx: That's totally right to asking the question if having any confusion, at the end all are here to learn. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Div - Viewmodel and DTO is different in MVVM (WPF) because VM there has behavior. In MVC they are same. And in no way `Note` in this case could be a ViewModel. It's purely an entity (OP is using EF I assume). May be you said so by mistake in your answer.

Comment: @NikhilVartak: Ohh, yes you're right! it was by mistake, thanks to pointed out. But I'm not agree with *In MVC they are same* They are different in MVC too, If we concern n-tire architecture, otherwise circular dependency comes to the picture!

Answer (score 0):

**Model** and **DTO** can be different. Both are used for different purpose. Here in your context I think you should create a new DTO (model)object which will contain only the required fields that you need to send from **DAL** to **BAL**. It will be more secure and faster as it will carry less data.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are only concerned about `WhatIsIt` that is striped down version of `Note` and will be the result of your DAL query. I have different opinion on this i.e. `WhatIsIt` should not be part of and thus returned from DAL to BLL. I will come back to this in a moment. Before that let's revise few terms.

*Domain / Business object* - They are usually same and include business logic.

*Domain object / DTO* - If business logic is performed outside of domain object then that object can be considered to be DTO that has nothing but properties and is used for data transfer across layers.

*Entity vs DTO* - Entity is purely part of data model and are used by ORMs or data access layer in general to work with data stores.

Now back to the point I made earlier - "`WhatIsIt` should not be part of and thus returned from DAL to BLL". To me `WhatIsIt` is a DTO that will be created by BLL once it gets the Entity object back from DAL (you already have referenced DAL in BLL so this should not be a problem). And then BLL will pass this DTO up to the presentation layer, ViewModel to be specific, if applicable.

Comment: So I should pass all data of Note Entity with Comments Entities to BLL and in BLL I should create DTO? Is it a good idea? Because I need only basic data of Notes and number of Comments.